# How does one overwrite the default compile flags for Cython when building with distutils?

Tags: distutils, cython

I am compiling some cython extensions in linux and noticed that it defaults to using -O2 when building from the distutils mechanism. I was wondering if there was a simple way to change that to a -O3.

I have tried using the extra_compile_args on Extension objects, but that leads to both -O2 and -O3 being passed as arguments to gcc. I kind of want to play with other esoteric gcc options and thus am hoping I can just control the compilation step. An obvious question is "why don't I just run cython my.pyx and compile the results manually?". I would love to, is my answer... but the cython executable in /usr/local/bin/ throws a DistributionNotFound: Cython==0.12.1 error when run from the command line. I haven't quite figured that one out.

Anyway, I am not sure if its a cython thing, a distutils thing or a broken apt package thing. I simply grabbed cython out of the ubuntu 11.10 apt repo (and am currently using ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: If you have Cython installed from apt, it shouldn't be in `/usr/local/bin`. Have you tried running `/usr/bin/cython` explicitly?

Comment: That question came to my mind yesterday :) I didn't found clean answer appart for redoing a crossplatform compiler extension ...

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423687/12141949) helps with your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

larsmans comment was right - using /usr/bin/cython addresses my issue.

Answer (score 18):

Using `extra_compile_args=["-O3"]` in your `setup.py`, the `-O3` should appear after the `-O2` option overriding it. Check the shared object (`.so`, or `.dll`) size in order to confirm it quickly.

Davide