# Cython: Compile Option -O3

Tags: gcc, cython, compiler-optimization

[How does one overwrite the default compile flags for Cython when building with distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236648/how-does-one-overwrite-the-default-compile-flags-for-cython-when-building-with-d)

My question is similar to this , but the response involved manually running the cython steps - given the progress from 0.12 to 01.9 - is it possible for me to simplyy switch from -O to  -O3?

Also have users seen a significant difference in speed depending on this switch?

I am on a windows machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use a setup.py script you can set the "extra_compile_args" option (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16402557/2355197). Depending on your code, you can see significant differences. For example, on GCC, -O3 enables the option "-finline-functions" which
considers all functions for inlining.

Davide

Comment: I'm not sure how well this works, since cython already adds `-O2`. If the compiler sees both `-O2` and `-O3`, which will it follow?