# How can I set Cython compiler flags when using pyximport?

Tags: python, cython

This question ([How does one overwrite the default compile flags for Cython when building with distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236648/how-does-one-overwrite-the-default-compile-flags-for-cython-when-building-with-d/16402557#16402557)) describes how to set default Cython flags when using distutils.

But how do I set default compile flags if I'm just using pyximport?

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()  # Pass compile flags here somehow?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use a `.pyxbld` file, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620003/how-do-you-tell-pyximport-to-use-the-cython-cplus-option).
For a file named `foo.pyx`, you would make a `foo.pyxbld` file. The following would give extra optimization args:

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
                     extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-march=native'])
```

I think it might be possible to pass in extra setup options to `pyximport.install` if you jump through enough hoops (messing around with `distribute`) to get the setup_args in the form it likes, however in the `pyximport` module documentation it recommends using a `.pyxbld` file, and in the test code for `pyximport` only that method is tested, so if there is another way it should be considered unstable/untested and `.pyxbld` should be considered the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Is the `.pyxbld` file documented **anywhere**? If it is, I'm failing to find it.

Comment: Ok. Is it documented anywhere that people actually use on a daily basis (read: somewhere I can find with google et. al)?

Comment: @FakeName Not as far as I know, but it is just plain text and you can read it in the git  repository: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/pyximport/pyximport.py or you could build it into a HTML file using a tool like pdoc, on the whole Cython online documentation is haphazard and you often have to go to the source files if you want to figure stuff out