# Is there a clean way to suppress compiler warnings from Cython when using pyximport.install?

Tags: python, cython

Say I have a simple package of the following structure:

```
cython_functions/
    __init__.py
    fib.pyx
```

where `fib.pyx` contains:

```
def fib(int n):
    fiblist = [0, 1]
    a, b = fiblist
    while b < n:
        a, b = b, a + b
        fiblist.append(b)
    return fiblist
```

and `__init__.py` contains:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from cython_functions.fib import fib
```

If I make any changes to `fib.pyx` I get a whole bunch of compiler warnings whenever I try to import the package:

```
/Users/andfranklin/.pyxbld/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pyrex/cython_functions/fib.c:1687:28: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyObject_AsString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject* o) {
                           ^
/Users/andfranklin/.pyxbld/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pyrex/cython_functions/fib.c:1684:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString(const char* c_str) {
                               ^
.
.
.
```

Is there any easy way to suppress them? In [another questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833947/how-can-i-set-cython-compiler-flags-when-using-pyximport) they describe how to pass compiler flags through an `.pyxbld` file. It is possible for me to create `fib.pyxbld` containing the following:

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
                     extra_compile_args=['-w'])
```

I would like to avoid this. If I need to create more functions I also need to create more `.pyxbld` files with the same boilerplate. This seems excessive and un-pythonic.

Answer (score 5):

I've battled this exact thing myself (glad to know I'm not alone!) and have not found a perfect solution. Unfortunately pyximport is rather opaque and doesn't AFAICT have much in the way of customizability.

But I do have what I think is a reasonable workaround, which helps especially once you have a growing number of Cython modules.

Basically, I have a module somewhere (let's say `common.cython`) that contains something like this:

```py
from distutils.extension import Extension


DEFAULT_EXTENSION_KWARGS = {
    "extra_compile_args": ["-w"]
}


def pyx_extension(**kwargs):
    for key, value in DEFAULT_EXTENSION_KWARGS.items():
        if key not in kwargs:
            kwargs[key] = value

    return Extension(**kwargs)


def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    return pyx_extension(name=modname, sources=[pyxfilename])
```

Basically a thin wrapper around the distutils `Extension` class, where I can set some custom defaults.

Then next to pyx modules that don't need any custom building, I put a `some_module.pyxbld` with just one line:

```py
from common.cython import make_ext
```

This works nicely because the .pyxbld file is just a python module that's expected to contain a `make_ext` function with that signature.

If I do need to customize the .pyxbld for the module, say if I need to add a C source file or something, it'll look something like this:

```py
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from common.cython import pyx_extension

    return pyx_extension(name=modname, sources=[pyxfilename, "my_extra_source.c"])
```

So, not *hugely* different from the basic documented way, but just enough to satisfy my [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) OCD :) Hope this helps, and please let me know if you find a better way.