# How can I import an external C function into an IPython Notebook using Cython?

Tags: python, c, ipython, cython

I'd like to import a C function into an IPython notebook using Cython. Currently, I'm trying to replicate the example in the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html), but I get a compilation error.

My Python code (from an iPython notebook):

```
import cython
%load_ext Cython
```

---------------------------------- new cell

```
%%cython
cdef extern from "spam.c":
    void order_spam(int tons)
```

My C code:

```
// spam.c
#include <stdio.h>

static void order_spam(int tons)
{
    printf("Ordered %i tons of spam!\n", tons);
}
```

Running this code, I get the following traceback and error message:

```
CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8bb733557977> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'cython', u'', u'\ncdef extern from "spam.c":\n    void order_spam(int tons)')

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2118             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2119             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2120                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2121             return result
   2122 

<decorator-gen-126> in cython(self, line, cell)

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/IpythonMagic.py in cython(self, line, cell)
    276             build_extension.build_temp = os.path.dirname(pyx_file)
    277             build_extension.build_lib  = lib_dir
--> 278             build_extension.run()
    279             self._code_cache[key] = module_name
    280 

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.pyc in run(self)
    337 
    338         # Now actually compile and link everything.
--> 339         self.build_extensions()
    340 
    341     def check_extensions_list(self, extensions):

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.pyc in build_extensions(self)
    446 
    447         for ext in self.extensions:
--> 448             self.build_extension(ext)
    449 
    450     def build_extension(self, ext):

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.pyc in build_extension(self, ext)
    496                                          debug=self.debug,
    497                                          extra_postargs=extra_args,
--> 498                                          depends=ext.depends)
    499 
    500         # XXX -- this is a Vile HACK!

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.pyc in compile(self, sources, output_dir, macros, include_dirs, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, depends)
    572             except KeyError:
    573                 continue
--> 574             self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    575 
    576         # Return *all* object filenames, not just the ones we just built.

/Users/danielacker/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.pyc in _compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    120                        extra_postargs)
    121         except DistutilsExecError, msg:
--> 122             raise CompileError, msg
    123 
    124     def create_static_lib(self, objects, output_libname,

CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried searching Google for this error, but I can't seem to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The `%cython` magic command probaby doesn't seem to do the trick.

The `%cython` magic command doesn't really do the task here. In order to compile this you need to also supply the `*.c` source file and that (as far as I'm aware) isn't allowed with `%cython`. (*[The source file for it indicates that it only uses the text entered in the cell as a source file.](https://github.com/davclark/ipython-extensions/blob/master/cythonmagic.py#L245)*)

#### Wrap your `C` functions:

Before presenting a probable solution, let me point out that the `.pyx` file you have created doesn't actually wrap the `C` function `order_spam` automatically. You can have it automatically wrapped if you specify it as `cpdef` inside the `cdef extern` block (alternatively you could wrap it on your own outside the `cdef extern` block, this allows more flexibility).

I'll use a filename of `cyspam.pyx` for the Cython file:

```
cdef extern from "spam.c":
    cpdef void order_spam(int tons)
```

Notice how I've prefixed the function declaration with `cpdef`, this instructs Cython to automatically wrap the function.

#### Use a `setup.py` script:

In order to have full control over the compilation process, you usually need to create a `setup.py` script that has all the required sources, include directories et cetera, specified.

Here's how the `setup.py` script should look like:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# you specify the c source file in the sources list
ext = Extension('cyspam', sources = ['cyspam.pyx', 'spam.c'])
setup(name="C spam", ext_modules = cythonize([ext]))
```

You can either create a file like this via a simple text editor or via `IPython` with the [**`%%writefile`**](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-writefile) magic command. The `setup.py` script should of course be placed in the same directory as the `cyspam.pyx` and `spam.c` files.

#### Compile the files:

You can either open a terminal for this or use the **[`%%bash`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-bash)** command from `IPython`, either way does the trick. Issue the following command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

`--inplace` places the generated `.so` file in the current directory.

After doing these you can easily import the file `cyspam` in `Ipython` and  just call the wrapped `C` function:

#### Rounding up all commands from `IPython`:

All in all, if you want to do it only from `IPython` you'll issue the following commands:

```
In [1]: %%writefile setup.py
   ....: from distutils.core import setup, Extension
   ....: from Cython.Build import cythonize
   ....: ext = Extension('cyspam', sources = ['cyspam.pyx', 'spam.c'])
   ....: setup(name="C spam", ext_modules = cythonize([ext]))

In [2]: %%bash
   ...: python setup.py build_ext --inplace

In [3]: import cyspam

In [4]: cyspam.order_spam(1000)
You ordered 1000 ammount of spam!
```

---

As an alternative you could always create a `.pyxbld` file that specifies the needed arguments for `pyximport.install()`. This offers the same level of control but is most likely counter-intuitive for Python users who already have experience with using `setup.py` scripts.

***See Related:***

[How can I set Cython compiler flags when using pyximport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833947/how-can-i-set-cython-compiler-flags-when-using-pyximport)

Comment: Sure you need to specify `spam.c` in `setup()`?  Simply `setup(ext_modules=cythonize('*.pyx', quiet=True)` seems to work