# compile Cython with specific compiler args

Tags: python, cython

When one runs the following code:

```
git clone https://github.com/cython/cython.git
sudo python setup.py install
```

cython (`Cython==0.24`) is compiled with the default compilation arguments. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236648/how-does-one-overwrite-the-default-compile-flags-for-cython-when-building-with-d), it used to be that one could add:

```
extra_compile_args=["-O3"]
```

to the `setup.py` file and control this. But I just tried it (by putting that line right below:

```
import platform
is_cpython = platform.python_implementation() == 'CPython'
```

) and when I do

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

all the files are still compiled with the dreaded `-O2` flag. How to fix this?

(I'm using linux)

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you `export CFLAGS="-O3"` it'll catch it, append it and use that over the default.

Comment: You mean add this command to `setup.py`?

Comment: No no, just run it from the terminal before running `setup.py`.

Comment: I see, try the alternative I added in the answer, couldn't add it as a comment here so I put it up as temporary shot at fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that using `export CFLAGS="-O3"` from the terminal before running `setup.py` (as I mentioned in the comment) generally does the trick, but, I just realized what you were trying to do.

You need to supply the `extra_compile_args` as an argument when creating the [`Extention`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) object(s) for the file(s) that need to be compiled. 
`extra_compile_args` is a list containing a string for every argument you want to supply.

In the `setup.py` script for the `Cython` lib, [that is performed in lines 163-166](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/setup.py#L163) if I am not mistaken.

In short, if you change those lines to:

```
    extensions.append(Extension(
        module, sources=[pyx_source_file],
        extra_compile_args=["-O3"],   # add the needed argument
        define_macros=defines_for_module,
        depends=dep_files))
```

It will make sure that every `.pyx` file that is compiled will have the `-O3` argument specified.

Comment: Are you supplying them as `extra_compiler_args=["-O3", "-march=native"]`? You need to supply a list of strings corresponding to arguments.